# Include Azure AD authentication in legacy “aspx” project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory, .aspxauth

I am searching a way to include authentication using Azure AD in a legacy web project (net framework 4 apsx) but I can’t found any doc or example, only for most recent MVC project, SPAs... 
Anyone have a reference for me?

Comment: Your project should be .net framework 4.5 + .

Comment: Ok, but after the update, how to configure for authentication with AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily implement authentication using Azure AD in your asp.net web project.

**Steps to follow:**

1. [Register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) in Azure AD.
2. Add target API, and grant consent to select [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration).
3. Choose your [authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols) for example [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
4. Implement the authentication flow as mentioned in the Microsoft document in your project. It is very simple and requires only get and post requests to implement.

Please let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a MVC application, it's a old "ASP.NET Web Application",unfortunally (Default.aspx... etc...)

Comment: Yes @GustavoAdolfo, Since yours is legacy project it is recommended to directly implementing OAuth in your project as mentioned in answer will work. It requires only HTTP get and post requests using URLs  to implement  which your legacy application can handle.

Comment: Base on more searches and mainly your answer and @jason’s comment I was able to create my solution. Tank’s for all.

Comment: @HariKrishna I'm working on a legacy ASP.NET 4.0/4.8 project (.aspx) and want to implement Microsoft Azure AD single sign-on. Do i need to create a new project with API endpoints and deploy it to IIS, and use those endpoints for login when a user clicks? or i can directly implement in my legacy app?   I've registered the app in Azure; any tutorials or guidance for integrating Azure AD SSO into my existing web project would be appreciated.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo Could you help me the process how you have implemented Azure Ad I am working with exactly same type of project that has default.aspx or global.aspx ?

Comment: Hi @Snooper_A. It's been a while since I left this project and I no longer have access, but I remember that the entire solution was based on Javascript using a library from Microsoft itself. I suggest you look at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js